# Retrieving Images From SharePoint through the Managed Client Object Model

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api

I'm trying to write some code to pull down images from SharePoint Foundation 2010 using the Managed Client Object Model.  Specifically, I'm trying to get the image bytes from images stored in the Site Assets Document Library.  Can anyone explain how to do this or provide some sample code? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should cover it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee956524.aspx

Also one for uploading file:
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sridhara/uploading-files-using-client-object-model-in-sharepoint-2010?wa=wsignin1.0)